# Simple Floating Point Calculations Produce Different Results

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 and have encountered a case where the same code  in two different versions of the same class library apparently produces different answers.

The following code reflects my attempts to reproduce the problem. It simply takes two pairs of numbers, (cx, cy) and (rx, ry), subtracts them, and displays the results (tx, ty) in decimal and hex format.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

string dhex(double x) {    // double to hex
   union {
      unsigned  long long n;
      double    d;
      } value;
   value.d = x;
   std::ostringstream buf;
   buf <<  "0x" << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(16) << value.n;
   return buf.str();
   }
double i64tod(unsigned long long n) {  // hex to double
   double *DP = (double *) &n;
   return *DP;
   }
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   double tx, ty, cx, cy, rx, ry;
   cx   = i64tod(0x3fb63f141205bc02); cy = i64tod(0x40019eb851eb851f);
   rx   = i64tod(0x3fa222fa84a5161c); ry = i64tod(0x40011f8441720667);
   tx   = cx - rx;
   ty   = cy - ry;
   cout << setprecision(22);
   cout << "  cx = " << setw(22) << cx << ", cy = " << setw(22) << cy
        << " (" << dhex(cx) << ", " << dhex(cy) << ")" << endl;
   cout << "  rx = " << setw(22) << rx << ", ry = " << setw(22) << ry 
        << " (" << dhex(rx) << ", " << dhex(ry) << ")" << endl;
   cout << "  tx = " << setw(22) << tx << ", ty = " << setw(22) << ty 
        << " (" << dhex(tx) << ", " << dhex(ty) << ")" << endl;
   return 0;
   }
```

The output from this code is:

```
  cx =   0.086900000000000005, cy =   2.2025000000000001   (0x3fb63f141205bc02, 0x40019eb851eb851f)
  rx =   0.035423115436554492, ry =   2.1403889763758346   (0x3fa222fa84a5161c, 0x40011f8441720667)
  tx =   0.051476884563445513, ty =   0.06211102362416554  (0x3faa5b2d9f6661e8, 0x3fafcd041e5fae00)
```

The application with the problem has a class library which is a "pool engine", ie. it simulates the physics of pool/snooker shots.

A recent set of changes to that library resulted in a failure of a verification test, which involves a particular sequence of shots that should produce a particular table state.

I tracked it down to that simple subtraction operation. When the new version executes the subtraction, it produces:

```
  cx =   0.086900000000000005, cy =   2.2025000000000001   (0x3fb63f141205bc02, 0x40019eb851eb851f)
  rx =   0.035423115436554492, ry =   2.1403889763758346   (0x3fa222fa84a5161c, 0x40011f8441720667)
  tx =   0.051476884563445513, ty =  ?0.062111023624165547 (0x3faa5b2d9f6661e8, 0x3fafcd041e5fae01)
```

As you can see the difference is in the least significant bit (of ty), but sometimes more than that. This is the result of another pair of point values:

```
  cx =  1.0641,                cy =  -0.0545               (0x3ff1068db8bac711, 0xbfabe76c8b439581)
  rx =  1.0878512271746064,    ry =   0.022594280641953058 (0x3ff167d6b03a0dee, 0x3f9722f481bc3f0d)
  tx = -0.023751227174606315,  ty =  -0.077094280641953061 (0xbf98523ddfd1b740, 0xbfb3bc736610da84)
```

The program above, and the older library version agree on this case too, but the new library version gives a different answer (for tx) in this case:

```
 tx = -0.023751227174606343,  ty =  -0.077094280641953061 (0xbf98523ddfd1b748, 0xbfb3bc736610da84)
```

Both versions of the library have the same compiler options, and the function in question (a collision handler) was not altered by the changes (I was just simplifying the library by replacing a class that had no methods with a struct).

I should add that when the new version gets a different result, at least it is consistent, ie. it ALWAYS produces those different answers.

I could simply accept the new version and replace the verification test with one that matches, but I would really like to know why this is happening.

For the record, I've tried to get the standalone program above to give the "alternative" answers by changing compiler options, etc, but no luck. It only fails in situ, in the new library version.

Comment: Required reading: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: We need a [mcve] to have even the foggiest idea  what's going on

Comment: Since in all of your post you never mentioned once about floating point being an approximation, I highly suggest you read more material on the inexactness of binary floating point.

Comment: In addition to preceding comments, visual studio has compilation options like `/fp` which disable some optimisations that affect precision of results from calculations using floating point types.    Have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7s85ffb.aspx.

Comment: Believe it or not, I am familiar with the "floating point" as approximation concept (irrelevant, we are talking simple addition/subtraction producing different results with same input), and the finer points of rounding errors, etc.

Comment: regarding /fp options, that's the first place I looked. Both projects use exactly the same (/fp:precise) and no module has any explicit settings that override this. The sample program above produces the same results for ALL /fp switch variations in any case.

Comment: What do you see (for the program that produces `0x3fafcd041e5fae01`) if you step through the program (maybe at assembly and register level of detail) and look at the instructions and memory/registers at the moment it performs the subtraction?

Comment: Looks like I might have to do just that. Setting it up as a debuggable object is a bit tricky, it's a DLL and I don't have a VC++ front-end for it. That makes we wonder whether the VB6 front-end that I am using could be altering the FP instruction context in some way? But the front-end is the same in either case, it just runs with whatever DLL version I make available.

Comment: The "floating point as approximation" concept is not irrelevant for addition and subtraction.   It affects ALL operations and sequences of operations.   Yes, the algorithm to be used to perform addition or subtraction is specified for some floating point representations (e.g. IEEE), but Microsoft compilers typically default to using a different representation for which that isn't true (which is one of several reasons that optimisation settings can affect results).

Comment: Fine, but would you not agree that the same source code (ie two simple subtractions), with the same  compiler options, and identical (bitwise) variable values should give the same result? Something weird is going on (which for MS compilers is nothing new, I suppose). I'm going to try and use BORG (disassembler) to see if the compiled code is in fact the same for both DLL versions.

Comment: Can you put the disassembly here for both versions?

Comment: The DLL's have over 4000 lines of code. But I have at least found one possible cause, and it does relate to FP rounding mode. I reported this in a separate question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45901052/dll-floating-point-results-differ-according-to-caller/45907069#45907069